# Set theory, images and preimages

Tags: set-theory

Let f:X→Y.
a)Show that f^−1(f(A)) ⊇ A for all A ⊆ X, and show that these two sets can be unequal.
b)Show that f(f^−1(B))⊆B for all B⊆Y

I would be very appreciative if someone can help me in these questions and help me on how to approach these exercises since i find this chapter quite challenging and i am not confident in my abilities

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to visualise what is going on by taking an example of any subset and function to know the intuition what is going on and do practice. It will help.

1st part:
Suppose x $\subseteq$ A.
Then f(x)$\subseteq$ f(A)
Imply $f^{-1}f(x)$ $\subseteq$ $f^{-1}f(A)$.
There can be more than one element belonging to $f^{-1}f(x)$.
But atleast x $\in$ $f^{-1}f(x)$.
So x belong to $f^{-1}f(A)$.
Imply E$\subseteq$$f^{-1}f(A)$

Second part
Suppose $$y\in ff^{-1}B$$
Then y=f(x) for some element x in $f^{-1}(B)$
But this imply y=f(x) and y belongs to $ff^{-1}B$
Imply y=f(x) and $f(x)\in B$.
Imply $y \in B$.
And hence $f(f^{-1}B)$$\subseteq$ B.